# opengl es render screen portion to texture

Tags: android, opengl-es

I'm using a FBO and I need to render a portion of the screen to a texture. I need to restrict the full screen render so I only get a small window of the screen rendered to the texture (I will then blur that portion and render it back to the screen as a texture).

Problem is I'm a little stuck with what to do with the viewport, perspective and view matrix. Can anyone help?

Comment: This is an almost exact duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24310536/opengl-render-portion-of-screen-to-texture/. You may want to check out the answers there. I can't officially nominate this as a dup because none of the answers were upvoted. My answer there offers a simpler solution that does not need any modification of perspective and view matrices.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you are drawing some scene and you want just a portion of that screen to be rendered to the FBO which has a proportional size depending on the portion you wish to redraw. Or in other words the FBO is just as large as the portion of the screen you wish to redraw.

After you created the FBO of proper size (might need POT dimensions) you need to set the viewport the same as the size of portion you are redrawing and origin stays at (0,0). The next thing you need to change is the projection part of the matrix which is in most cases either `glOrtho` or `glFrustum`. Both of these have 4 border parameters (left, right, top, bottom). These parameters need to be set to what part of the scene you are redrawing which depends on both, how your border parameters are set on the main scene and in what coordinate system your redraw rect is defined. For instance if you want to redraw the top left 100x100 part of the screen and use `glOrtho` and border parameters as `(0,0,viewWidth,viewHeight)` then your new border parameters are simply `(0,0,100,100)`. But if you use something like `(-1,-1,1,1)` then those parameters would need to be computed depending on your screen (buffer) size.

Anyway, you should be able to manage it by changing only these 2 methods. Do not forget to reset them after you are done with drawing to the FBO.

**EDIT: Coordinate system transformation**

Although this has been answered quite a lot more then a few times here is a bit of math code to transform from one coordinate system to another. Generally inserting your true parameters from the original scene this should give you the transformed border parameters which you should insert into your FBO frustum.

(I did not test this so mistakes may have been made)

```
    BorderParameters screenRect; // for instance (0, 0, 360, 480) (left, top, right, bottom)
    BorderParameters redrawRect; // for instance (0, 0, 36, 48) (left, top, right, bottom)
    BorderParameters frustumRect; // for instance (-1, ratio, 1, -ratio) (left, top, right, bottom)

    BorderParameters outputRect; // result (insert into ortho or frustum)

    outputRect.left = frustumRect.left + ((redrawRect.left-screenRect.left)/(screenRect.right-screenRect.left))*(frustumRect.right-frustumRect.left);
    // -1 + ((0-0)/(360-0))*(1+1) = -1
    outputRect.right = frustumRect.left + ((redrawRect.right-screenRect.left)/(screenRect.right-screenRect.left))*(frustumRect.right-frustumRect.left);
    // -1 + ((36-0)/(360-0))*(1+1) = -.8
    outputRect.bottom = frustumRect.top + ((redrawRect.bottom-screenRect.top)/(screenRect.bottom-screenRect.top))*(frustumRect.bottom-frustumRect.top);
    // ratio + ((48-0)/(480-0))*(-ratio-ratio) = ratio - .2*ratio = .8*ratio
    outputRect.top = frustumRect.top + ((redrawRect.top-screenRect.top)/(screenRect.bottom-screenRect.top))*(frustumRect.bottom-frustumRect.top);
    // ratio + ((0-0)/(480-0))*(-ratio-ratio) = ratio
```

I am kind of 50% sure this whole procedure will work with frustum now that I think of it but, there might be a slight offset on the redrawn part (if its a large one there is an issue with parameters). 
Anyway it is more usual to draw the whole scene to a FBO and then redraw it to the main buffer with the post processing rather then redrawing all the elements to a small FBO as there might be lots of elements to redraw to the FBO. Also what happens if you want many (10 for instance) small parts of the screen to be blurry at the same time, will you redraw the whole scene 11 times to get the scene plus the 10 FBOs?

Comment: Very, very helpful thanks. I have been doing more research, like here: :http://www.songho.ca/opengl/gl_transform.html#example2. How do I calculate the required glFrustrum from the screen co-ordinates of the area I want to render to the buffer?